# RowDetailsTemplateSelector based on data value won't update

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, rowdetailstemplate

I have a datagrid with a RowDetailsTemplateSelector that uses a value in the bound data object to determine which datatemplate to use.  The issue is that when I change and even commit the value of the value, the template doesn't switch to the appropriate one.  What is the trigger that would cause the template to change?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?